# How to retrieve the latest conversations in an XMPP client

Tags: xmpp, chat, thunderbird

When I close Thunderbird, Miranda or another jabber client, I lose the chats of all unsubscribed contacts.

The process is as follows:

1. Someone new starts a chat with me for the first time.
2. I close Thunderbird.
3. When I open it again, I can't get the conversation back with that person.

Is there any way to configure the server or chat clients to not lose those conversations?

Answer (score 0):

MongooseIM tackled this problem with the custom module [mod_inbox](https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/mod_inbox/). I don't know if this works with Thunderbird though.